# Get Closest Form to an Element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have this js/jquery script i wrote to check all checboxes with in a form. It works well but this checks all checkboxes that are on page irrespective of the form wrapper they are.

here is the function

```
function toggleCheck(state)
{   var checkboxes = jQuery("form input:checkbox");
if(state==true){checkboxes.prop('checked',true); }
if(state==false){ checkboxes.prop('checked',false); }
}
```

usage

```
<a id="check" href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleCheck(true);" class="btn">Select All</a>
<a id="uncheck" href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleCheck(false);" class="btn">Deselect All</a>
```

Note this works well but my problem is if i have

```
 <form action="myaction-page">//some form elements and checkboxes </form>
```

and

```
<form action="myaction-page-2">//some form elements and checkboxes </form>
```

and i click the check all link in form1, all checkboxes gets check including those in form2.

Is there a way to separate them without introducing form ids or names?..this is because i have used it extensively in production code and to rewrite all will be trouble.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S it is worth noting that the select all and deselect all are within both forms and both forms are on the same page.

Comment: Are your "select all" and "deselect all" checkboxes inside the forms?

Comment: Why do you have an if statement? `checkboxes.prop('checked',state);`

Comment: @JasonP yes the select all and deselect all are in both forms....they are suppose to select based on the form they belong

Comment: @KevinB except if state is undefined

Comment: @KevinB not sure i understand you...if you mean if statements in the js function then yes i do have...take a look at the function

Comment: @VyrenMedia He's saying they are unnecessary. `if (someBool == true) { doSomething(true); } else if (someBool == false) { doSomething(false); }` is the same as `doSomething(someBool);`

Comment: @JasonP wow i didn't know that...guess we learn every day...in that case will be writing like this now.

Comment: @VyrenMedia How many pages have multiple forms? All of them?

Comment: not all pages have multiple forms about 20 or so

Comment: Then you should probably just bite the bullet and do it right. Give the checkboxes classes and attach the handler with jQuery.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming your select/deselect links are inside the form, do:

```
function toggleCheck(state,elem) {
    jQuery(elem).closest("form").find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', state);
}
```

And change your link JS to (passing the appropriate true/false parameter):

```
onclick="javascript:toggleCheck(false,this);"
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KLUAX/3/)**

Comment: having to update the anchor element is going to pose trouble as i have over 50 pages set up this way...thanks for the answer tho!

Comment: If you can't update the anchor element, then you're out of luck. without updating it there's no way of automatically targeting the element (in all browsers). That's what you (or whoever wrote the code) gets for using inline-events, code that is difficult/impossible to maintain.

Comment: @KevinB - could we do `jQuery(event.target).closest("form").find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', state);`?

Comment: is `event` defined in all browsers globally? I know it will work in Chrome, but i somehow doubt that's always going to be the case.

Comment: @VyrenMedia There are editors out there that allow you to easily replace x with y, notepad++ for example. You could replace all occurences of `toggleCheck\((true|false)+\)` with `toggleCheck($1,this)` in one sweep using the regexp flag and replace in files under a specific directory at once. It will even let you filter to only files that match a specific pattern.

Comment: @KevinB i didnt write the code entirely, am more of a back-end developer(PHP/Python) the front end guy did it..however, he is sick and i was called in to cover till hez back.

Comment: I'd definitely suggest just going with the find/replace with an editor that can search through a directory, it'd be the least intrusive solution to this problem, meaning you'd solve the problem with the least amount of changes to the way the code works, which isn't a bad idea considering it isn't your code.

Comment: thanks for this info @KevinB so on a final note, i go with this answer and update all ahchor tags?

Comment: Well, any of these solutions would work, no matter which one you choose you're going to have to update the anchor tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody for your contributions...i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: it depends on your DOM. If your `<a>` elements are inside the form, you could use [$.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
function toggleCheck(state) {
    $(this)
        .closest("form")
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .prop('checked', state);
}
```

I slightly altered your code to increase readability, performance (see the additional notes regarding the [:checkbox selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)) and be more "jQuery"-like.

[edit]
After reading the comments I rewrote the function, still on the assumption that the `<a>` elements are inside the `<form>`, this time also with a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw5jB/1/):

```
function toggleCheck(state) {
    $(document).find(event.target)
        .closest("form")
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .prop('checked', state);
}
```

[edit2]
And for the sake of completness regarding my comment about the order of the elements ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw5jB/4/)):

```
function toggleCheck(state) {
    var pos = $(document).find(event.target.localName + "." + event.target.className).index(event.target);
    var $form = $($(document).find("form").get(Math.floor(pos/2)));
    $form
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .prop('checked', state)
}
```

[edit3]
The last edit, I promise. This time I ignore the default callback and do [my own thing](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw5jB/5/):

```
function toggleCheck(state) {
    // either write the s tate now in a variable for
    // the next callback
}

$(document).on("click", "a.btn", function(e) {
    var $ele = $(this);
    // or do some string exploration
    var toggle = $ele.attr("onclick").indexOf("true") > -1;

    var pos = $(document).find("a.btn").index($ele);
    var $form = $($(document).find("form").get(Math.floor(pos/2)));
    $form
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .prop('checked', toggle);
});
```

Works without having to touch anything. But I wouldn't want to use this. ;-)

Comment: @VyrenMedia Not if it is inside the `<form>` element, then everything should work as is. If they're not, one would have to cheat a little bit (assuming the the first `<a>` elements toggle the first `<form>` and so on…

Comment: @nietonfir `this` references the window in this case, and the window most definitely is not inside a form.

Comment: @KevinB Damned, you're right. But he mustn't use `toggleCheck`, he could simply listen to the click event globally and toggle accordingly (assumgin the first `<a>` elements toggle the first `<form>`and so on…), don't u think?

Comment: @nietonfir just tried your code and it didn't work...i really appreciate your contribution.

Comment: Yes, but that would still mean modifying the anchor tag, or at least removing the onclick event. programmatically.

Comment: @nietonfir "But he mustn't use toggleCheck, he could simply listen to the click event globally and toggle accordingly" i like where this is going...could you expanciate please...

Comment: the fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/Sw5jB/) does not work...details(Mozilla Firefox 23, Windows 8)

Comment: Right, that will only work in browsers that have `event` defined on window, firefox isn't one of them.

Comment: @KevinB Touché. But I got one last solution incoming. ;)

Comment: Now if only you could ensure that the element is a toggleCheck element and not just some other random anchor with a .btn class, that's entirely possible.

Comment: Well, `indexOf("toggleCheck")` on the onclick attribute should cover that as well. But seriously, this snippet is broken by design and just begs to break things apart… ;-)

Answer (score 1):

the .closest method will do what you want.

onclick:

```
onclick="toggleCheck.call(this,true);"
```

js:

```
function toggleCheck(state) {   
    var checkboxes = jQuery(this).closest("form").find("input:checkbox");
    checkboxes.prop('checked',state || false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just apply a data-target to your anchors and eval based on the action of your form elements:

```
... data-target='myaction-page' ...

... checkboxes[i].form.getAttribute( 'action' ) ...
```

Shown in detail on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXVdL/3/)

Comment: if i update all the anchor tags on all pages what stops me from updating the onclick attribute as advised by other answers...thanks all the same.