# Submit a form via this object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I want to submit, and I don't know the best way to call the form.
This is my HTML

```
<form id="form2" name="form2">
<select id="situation_matrimoniale" name="situation_matrimoniale">
    <option value="Célibataire">Célibataire</option>
    <option value="Marié(e)">Marié(e)</option>
    <option value="Veuf(ve)">Veuf(ve)</option>
    <option value="Divorcé(e)">Divorcé(e)</option>
</select><input type="text" name="nombre_enfant" id="nombre_enfant" value="" /><input type="button" value="Enregistrer" name="submit" onclick="submitFormInfoEtatCivil()" />
</form>
```

Now the Javascript, I included jQuery.

```
function submitFormInfoEtatCivil() {
            
    var update = "index.php/rh/updateinfo";
    var dataString = $( this ).serialize();
    
    // dataString return <empty string>
    
    jQuery.ajax({
        
    });
        
}
```

I have many forms with ids : form1, form2, form3 ...
My problem is how to specify the fonction submitFormInfoEtatCivil() to get the form where button is submitted. I used $( this ).serialize() but I am wrong because the output is empty.

Comment: @RyanWilson I have many forms. I look for a way to refer to the form where I click the submit button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Closest Form to an Element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168919/get-closest-form-to-an-element-in-jquery)

Comment: @RyanWilson I first tried it, but it didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `this` inside function and then use `.closest("form")` to get input datas from form where button has been clicked.

***Demo Code :***

```js
function submitFormInfoEtatCivil(el) {
  var update = "index.php/rh/updateinfo";
  //use closest to get form where button is clicked
  var dataString = $(el).closest("form").serialize();
  console.log(dataString)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form2" name="form2">
  <select id="situation_matrimoniale" name="situation_matrimoniale">
    <option value="Célibataire">Célibataire</option>
    <option value="Marié(e)">Marié(e)</option>
    <option value="Veuf(ve)">Veuf(ve)</option>
    <option value="Divorcé(e)">Divorcé(e)</option>
  </select><input type="text" name="nombre_enfant" id="nombre_enfant" value="" />
  <!--pass `this` inside function-->
  <input type="button" value="Enregistrer" name="submit" onclick="submitFormInfoEtatCivil(this)" />
</form>
<form id="form" name="form">
  <select id="situation_matrimoniale" name="situation_matrimoniale">
    <option value="Célibataire">Célibataire</option>
    <option value="Marié(e)">Marié(e)</option>
    <option value="Veuf(ve)">Veuf(ve)</option>
    <option value="Divorcé(e)">Divorcé(e)</option>
  </select><input type="text" name="nombre_enfant" id="nombre_enfant" value="" />
  <!--pass `this` inside function-->
  <input type="button" value="Enregistrer" name="submit" onclick="submitFormInfoEtatCivil(this)" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` that you use refers to button and you are getting empty string when you are `serialize()` a button.

I strongly recommend an another solution for this problem; you can catch the form when it is submitted with the `on()` function;

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
  var thiz = $(this);
  var update = thiz.attr("form-url"); //get update url from the form as an attiribute or define it staticly.
  var dataString = thiz.serialize();

  return false; //to prevent original form action.
});
```

When you use above code snippet you can remove `onclick="submitFormInfoEtatCivil(this)"` from your code and also if you want to deep dive with `on()` function, you can find [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/) an documentation.

Comment: What happens if the button is no longer the direct child of the form?